# Benefits of using UISearchController?

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

What's the benefit of using `UISearchController` over `UISearchBarDelegate`? The difference seems kind of subtle to me. In particular, `updateSearchResults` seems essentially the same as `textDidChange`. Assuming we don't use a new VC to display the search results, I can't see why one should add `UISearchController` on top of `UISearchBarDelegate`.

Answer (score 7):

From the documentation for `UISearchController`:

> You use a search controller in tandem with your existing view controllers. When you have a view controller with searchable content, incorporate the search bar of a `UISearchController` object into your view controller’s interface. When the user interacts with that search bar, the search controller automatically displays a new view controller with the search results that you specify.
>
> Each search controller provides a UISearchBar object that you must incorporate into the user interface of your initial view controller. Add this object to the view containing your searchable contents. When the user taps the search bar to enter a search term, the search controller automatically displays your search results view controller and notifies your app that the search process has begun.

Basically, the search controller handles the grunt work of displaying the search results controller, animating the search bar to the header, graying out the results if there is nothing entered, etc.. It does a lot of the grunt work for you when switching between your regular view controller and the results controller.

When you don't need (or want) all of that helpful work done for you and you want to show your own search bar, or your main view controller can easily show the search results, then you don't need to use a `UISearchController`.

This is similar to asking why you should use a `UINavigationController` when you can add your own `UINavigationBar` and delegate or why use a `UITabBarController` when you can add your own `UITabBar` and delegate. It's all a matter of convenience and user interface consistency.

Comment: Could you clarify "animating the search bar to the header"? When you say "graying out the results if there is nothing entered", I'm guessing you mean it hides the search results controller. I guess I'm thinking mostly about the use case where the searchResultsController is set to nil. Would there be any justification for using UISearchController in that case?

Comment: When you fully implement a search controller, tapping on the search field will result in the search bar animating up to the top of the screen and animating the results controller into view. When nothing is entered into the search field, the result view is grayed out.